# Build error when signing with snk key

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2015, snk

Build error is occurring since using Visual Studio 2015. When building in Visual Studio 2015 this is occurring rarely. When building in TeamCity this occurs very often.

[Error in Visual Studio 2015]

- *Error extracting public key from file 'CompanyName.snk': The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2FF6.tmp' because it is being used by another process.  CompanyName.Project.DAL D:\Projecten\CompanyName\Repository\Source\Components\CompanyName.Project.DAL\vbc*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKbbe.png

[Error in TeamCity]

- *CSC error CS7027: Error signing output with public key from file 'CompanyName.snk' -- The process cannot access the file 'C:\BuildAgents\Gamma\temp\buildTmp\tmpD91D.tmp' because it is being used by another process.*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbgHx.png

Comment: It looks like the problem with multicore build. Have you tried to build your solution with single instance of MSBuild (without /m switch)? Have you tried to diagnose the detailed output log of MSBuild? Have you tried to determine which process own the temp file?

Comment: I've started seeing this issue on our Jenkins build server within the last week! I use 4 cores (/m:4) when building. It seems to happen at random and with different projects every time. I've never had the error locally. Only from the build server.

Comment: Started seeing this all of a sudden in our build server, and it turned out to be a recent update (July 2020) to Windows Defender, see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603715/63209).

Answer (score 14):

I know it's been a while since this was asked but as I use SO for my own reference and I had this problem too I wanted to share my solution.

.snk files are for signing a project. You might need to make a new one.

- Right click on your project, select properties.
- Click on Signing.
- Click the checkbox beside "Sign the assembly".
- On the dropdown labelled "Choose a strong name key file" click new.
- Fill in the dialog box as you wish noting particularly the Key file name. When you press ok, this will generate a new .snk file.
- Save the project and rebuild.
- This will use the new .snk in your project and will resolve the
  error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will give it a try, for now I just removed the signing on the project. Also solved it as a workaround :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try to clean up the temp folder that is used by the build.
I have seen different types of problems when the temp folder has lots of files.

Some of the tools are using GetTempFileName and they will get errors when temp has a lots of files

**The [GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method will raise an IOException if it is used to create more than 65535 files without deleting previous temporary files.**

Comment: The amount of files in the temp folders of the agent are limited. Is this the temp folder you are referring to?

Comment: Was exactly this. The temp folder for the user running the build (`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp`) was having more than 65535 files.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2840) with Roslyn compiler. The workaround would be adding

```
<UseSharedCompilation>False</UseSharedCompilation>
```

under any `<PropertyGroup>` node in .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

It started for me when I moved the Resharper Cache to System Temp. When I moved it back to the Solution folder, the problem went away, and I could build again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. In Visual Studio 2015, I fixed it using the following steps:

1. Go to Tools > Options
2. From the Options dialog, select "Projects and Solutions > Build and Run"
3. Set the "maximum number of parallel project builds" to 1

+1 to @stukselbax for getting me on the right track
[Also got help from this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I used '/m:1' as an msbuild argument, and 'SignPublic' property to true in the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue today in visual Studio 2022- I was messing with the csproj file and ended up having the wrong filepath to the snk file. I fixed it by changing the filepath to be correct.

1. Right-click on the project -> unload (so that you can edit the csproj file)
2. Under `<PropertyGroup>` check the `<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>` tag
3. My code was:`<SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly> <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>../NAMEHERE.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>` NAMEHERE was specific to my project, yours will vary. Look at your snk file. The ../ in front will vary, check the filepath of your snk file. If you caused this error by messing with your csproj file, like I did, then the correct answer is what the filepath was before you changed it. :)
4. Right-click on the project -> reload

Answer (score 0):

double click on your project and set to false:

```
  <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly> 
 <PublicSign>false</PublicSign>
```

remove this line :

```
 <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>CompanyName.snkk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```