# Error signing output with public key from file snk - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and opened an existing solution (previously opened in Visual Studio 2015). Everything seems to open fine. I can see the solution, files, edit files, etc... However, when I attempt to build the solution, I get the following error:

> Error signing output with public key from file 'redacted.snk' -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

The closest related SO question I could find is [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971642/build-error-when-signing-with-snk-key). I have attempted all of the recommendations with no success, including:

- Cleaning my temp folder
- Editing the csproj with the UseSharedCompilation tag
- Set the "maximum number of parallel project builds" to 1
- Restarted my computer

I'm running out of ideas on this one. Not sure what to try next. My hunch is that the error isn't 100% accurate (i.e. the file is not being used by another process), and that this has something to do with the upgrade to VS2017.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? If so, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Jim, IIRC, I believe the problem went away with a VS update. However, since it's been over a year, I could be wrong. Can't remember, TBH. Sorry :(