# Error Signing output with public key from file 'x.snk' -- the process being used by another process

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio

I am getting this Build error (in Visual Studio 2017) all of a sudden on my solution which was working absolutely fine some time ago and I am totally confused what is the reason behind it. Things I have tried to resolve this are -
1. Restart the machine
2. Clear temp folder
3. Change Build settings to use single thread while building
4. Update Visual Studio 2017 to latest
5. Reinstall Visual Studio

After all this the issue is still unsolved and my work is totally blocked.
Can someone please guide me what can be possible solution?

Comment: "the process being used by another process"    please copy the details of the error accurately. Somewhere you have a file that's locked by another process, probably the vshost.exe process.

Comment: Where is the `x.snk` file? Such exceptions are quite common if it is on a network drive and someone else is using it,

Comment: The exception log in the Output window is 'CSC : error CS7027: Error signing output with public key from file 'keyfile_CA2210.snk' -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)'. And the file is locally present and not used by any other process. I have confirmed this by Process Explorer. I am clueless how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update to Visual Studio appears to have introduced something that the anti-virus program does not like.
I had the same issue, and it got fixed when the security admin in my organization edited the anti-virus settings to ignore certain files.
This is not a robust solution as it can leave the computer vulnerable to attacks. However, it is a workaround until the Visual Studio Developer Community fixes the issue.
Please see
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/299998/unable-to-build-a-strongly-signed-assembly-on-visu.html

Comment: Nothing on that link shows that there was even an issue with the Visual Studio (not to mention that VS devs will fix anything). The comment clearly says "After investigation, we've found nothing unusual about the compiler access pattern for key files. This seems a likely bug in your antivirus software. Unfortunately, there's nothing we've found that the compiler can do to mitigate the problem."

Comment: +1 because this did point me in the right direction: looks like Windows Defender became too aggressive after a recent (July 2020) update, causing this problem. The solution was to exclude various build processes (devenv.exe, msbuild.exe, vbcscompiler.exe) and folders from scanning.