# CSC : error CS7028: Error signing output with public key from container 'Container' -- The file exists. [lgw0hqij.tmp_proj]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

We had a Jenkins job running without issues for a couple of months now but recently it started failing.

It has this error when running form Jenkins:

```
CSC : error CS7028: Error signing output with public key from container 'Container_ID' -- The file exists. [lgw0hqij.tmp_proj]
```

It seems to rename the file every time.

I have logged into the host and executed as the user but it gives no error when running normally. 
Once I run the user as an administrator, it starts giving the issue.

Running the application from Visual Studio does not give an issue at all!

I have tried running Jenkins as a LocalService as well as a lower privileged user, but same result.

I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628486/2873946), but doesn't seem to help.

I'm running out of ideas

---

EDIT

For anyone facing the same issue in the future. This error is linked to the user account temp folder

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Once you clear this folder, your msbuild should be working fine

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue in the future. This error is linked to the user account temp folder

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Once you clear this folder, your msbuild should be working fine

Comment: Hi friend, since you have a workaround, I suggest you could add an answer rather than a comment and then [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). It will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Thanks:)

Comment: Thank you @PerryQian-MSFT. My stackoverflow knowledge is terrible, but I added the recommendation as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue in the future. This error is linked to the user account temp folder

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Once you clear this folder, your msbuild should be working fine